# How to call the "Sort By" feature in Left Column in Category page

Tags: sorting

I have to show the "Sort By" feature in Left Column along with the other Attributes. How to call the Sort by in the left section specifically in layered navigation section. I want something like this website **http://www.glasses.com/mens** 
Any hint can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1. add the block to where you want.**

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="sortby" template="catalog/product/list/sortby.phtml">
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar_sortby" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_sortby.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar_sortby</name></action>
</block>
```

**2. app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/sortby.phtml**

```
<?php
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
?>

<?php if($_productCollection->count()): ?>

<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar_sortby.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**3. app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar_sortby.phtml**

you can customize from `toolbar.phtml`